# Jquery Code for this

Tags: jquery

Exact jquery code for this(rough) condition

```
if(searchTerm.length==0){
    alert("empty")
}  
else{
    form.submit
}
```

**My HTML Code**

```
<input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="button"/>
```

Is this script relevent??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $("#button").click(function () {
          var abc = $("searchTerm").val();
          if (abc.length == 0) {
              alert("alert")
          }
          return false;
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't a question, you're just asking people to write this code for you.  Please put it in the form of a question.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question dude...

Comment: Please, enlighten me. I do not know what the OP is asking.

Comment: People need to stop with these "this-aint-a-question" accusations, sometimes the author doesn't know exactly what to ask, that's what stack overflow is for. So stop getting mad at people for doing that. I certainly had no idea what to ask when I was first learning.

Comment: @JamesKyle Well said....I appreciate what you said....

Comment: guys i am simply asking relevant Jquery script that works on my form elements (with a condition). Now the condition is submit form data to some controller action when form elements hold some value , if not then display a simple alert "provide an input"

Comment: Sorry my appologies to readers.

Comment: @dhiraj.Saini no need to apologize, never apologize for asking for help, its the smart thing to do

Comment: You really can't accept any of the answers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val();
    if(searchTerm.length == 0){
        alert("empty");
    }  else{
        $("#formID").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks brenjt. let me know one thing more if statement support && .I am asking this b'coz i tried it and error comes

Comment: $("#button").click(function () {


                if ($("#searchTerm").val().length == 0 && $("#searchTerm1").val().length == 0) {
                    alert("Enter Valid Characters");
                }
                else {
                    $("#formID").submit();
                }
            });

Answer (score 1):

Try this Optimized **Jquery** to reuse same `if` condition for other form

```
$("#button").click(function(){
var searchboxid = $("#button").attr("searchboxid");
var formid = $("#button").attr("formid");
    if($("#"+searchboxid).val()==""){ 
        alert("empty")
    }  
    else{
        $("#"+formid).submit();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="formHere">
    <input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" type="text" />
    <input type="button" id="button" searchboxid="searchTerm" formid="formHere" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is working fine but now i want to add another if condition "&&". i.e want to check another form element with same condition

Comment: @dhiraj.Saini Sorry for late reply....Check out the edited code for check another form element with same condition...Please accept the answer if helpful....Their is a green right mark to accept the answer...

Answer (score 0):

[**working example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/soul/DVdby/3/)

```
  $("#button").live("click",function(){
          var abc = $("#searchTerm").val();
         alert(abc );
          var abcLength = $("#searchTerm").length;
          alert(abcLength );
                if (abc  == "") {
              alert("alert")
          }
         else{
     alert("alert length is not equal to zero");
    // form.submit 
    }

      });
```